# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in

Tags: php, android, binding

I saw many questions with that headline. But none of their solutions could solve my problem.Here is my problem;

```
public function getLiveWallPost(){
$acik="smthng";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT text_id,type,header,body,date FROM text WHERE type = ? order by text_id desc limit 20");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $acik);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($text_id,$type,$header,$body,$date);                        
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $post['text_id']=$text_id
        $post['type']=$type;
        $post['header']=$header;
        $post['body']=$body;
        $post['date']=$date;
        $postsArray[]=$post;
    }
    return $postsArray;
}
```

}

this one is working correctly but ,

```
public function getLiveWallPostNext20($id){
$acik="smthng";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT text_id,type,header,body,date FROM text WHERE type = ? and WHERE text_id < ? order by text_id desc limit 20");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $acik,$id);      //line 46
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($text_id,$type,$header,$body,$date);                        
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $post['text_id']=$text_id
        $post['type']=$type;
        $post['header']=$header;
        $post['body']=$body;
        $post['date']=$date;
        $postsArray[]=$post;
    }
    return $postsArray;
}
```

}

this one giving me bind_param() on a non-object error at line 46. Only difference between them is, one of them uses 1 parameter and other one uses 2 parameters.

Comment: Remove `where` after  `and condition` at `and WHERE text_id  < ? order`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked ! actually it is very simple mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT text_id,type,header,body,date FROM text WHERE type = ? and text_id < ? order by text_id desc limit 20");
```

Remove `WHERE` before `text_id < ?`